# How to direct NSTask output to NSTextField in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, stdout

So currently I'm working on a little personal project that runs a bash script in a resources bundle, and I can get it to properly output the console log to NSLog, but the strings won't rewrite an NSTextField or redraw an NSTextView

```
- (IBAction)doIt:(NSButton *)sender
{
    NSTask *task;
    task = [[NSTask alloc] init];
    [task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/sh"];

    NSArray *arguments;
    NSString* newpath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"run" ofType:@"sh"];
    NSLog(@"shell script path: %@",newpath);
    arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:newpath, nil];
    [task setArguments: arguments];

    NSPipe *pipe;
    pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
    NSPipe *input = [NSPipe pipe];
    [task setStandardOutput: pipe];
    [task setStandardInput: input];

    NSFileHandle *file;
    file = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
    [task launch];

    NSData *data;
    data = [file readDataToEndOfFile];

    NSString *string;
    string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSLog (@"script returned:\n%@", string);
}
```

So the string at the end will output properly with NSLog, but that's all I can do... any ideas?

Comment: the answer to this [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635086/nstask-character-output-to-nstextfield-unbuffered-as-continuous-stream?rq=1) might help you out...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You will need to create an `NSTextField` or `NSTextView`, either in your XIB file or programmatically in your code.

If you'd like to create it in your XIB file, here's how to do it (for ARC):

1) Add an `IBOutlet` property to your .h file in your controller (e.g. AppDelegate):

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSTextField *textField;
```

OR

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSTextView *textView;
```

2) Go to your XIB file, create a new `NSTextField` or `NSTextView` and put it on a window. Right-click on your controller class and drag a connection to your `NSTextField` or `NSTextView`.

3) Now that the `IBOutlet` is connected to your view in your XIB, all you need to do is set the string value in your .m file by calling

```
[self.textField setStringValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"script returned:\n%@", string]];
```

for an `NSTextField`

OR

```
[self.textView setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"script returned:\n%@", string]];
```

for an `NSTextView`

I hope this helps.